# How to connect Python arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I  don't understand when it is sum operation or just connect two arrays

```
x = np.arange(10)
x
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

x[4]=44
x
#array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 44,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])

xs=np.split(x,5)
xs
#[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([44,  5]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
```

what is this shape  ?

```
xs=np.split(x,5)
xs
#[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([44,  5]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]

i=2
xscn = np.concatenate((xs[:i]+xs[i+1:]))
xscn
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

"so why it no summing the array just put them side side (not ariane grande ha ha ha"

```
f=(xs[:i]+xs[i+1:])
f

#[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
```

so it just put one array after other.

```
cc=np.concatenate(f)   
cc  
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9])

ff=xs[:i]+xs[i+1:]
ff
#[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
```

so when it adds and when it just sets one list after other also I can't type the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `type(np.split(x, 5)) == list`, and `list`s don't have a `shape`, but you can find their `len`gths;
2. `xs` is a `list`, so adding two lists concatenates them:

   ```
   xs[:i]+xs[i+1:] == [array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
   ```

   Then you `concatenate` all of these tiny arrays into one, which gives you back your original array.
3. Same reason as above
4. Same reason as above

The problem is, Python `list`s are *not* NumPy `ndarray`s, and behave differently.